# Prolog simple rules

Tags: prolog

Started learning Prolog 2 days ago and came across this problem, I'm trying to program both rules at the end but they don't seem to work correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
% gender/2: identifies the gender of a person

gender(beto,male).
gender(willy,male).
gender(caonabo,male).
gender(haley,female).
gender(mary,female).
gender(yoli,female).

%friend/2 specifies the friendship between two persons

friend(beto,willy).
friend(willy,caonabo).
friend(willy,haley).
friend(haley,mary).
friend(haley,yoli).

% Rule to know if a person has any female friends
has_fFriend(person):- friend(person,friend),genero(friend,female).


% Rule to know if the person has any friends of it's same gender
homofriend(person):- friend(person,friend), gender(person,X) == gender(friend,X).
```

Comment: Variables start with Uppercase or _underscore.

Comment: In Prolog words starting with small letters are constant. If you want a variable, then you should use a word starting with capital letter. So some thing like `has_fFriend(Person) :- friend(Person, Friend), genero(Friend, female).` should work.